# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

Tags: php, contact-form, php-parse-error

I'm new to coding and after hosting my site I got this error when checking to make sure my php contact form was working:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING on line 16
```

the php code is:

```
<?php

$subject="subject";

$message="$message";

$mail_from="$email";

$header="from: $name <$mail_form>";

$to='fearnstj@vcu.edu';

$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

if($send_contact){
    echno "Thank You!" "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'> Return Home </a>";
}
else{
    echno "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've not heard of an `echno` command. Perhaps you mean **`echo`**?

Comment: `echno`?!? do you mean `echo`?

Comment: I was receiving this error and had to convert the file line separators from CF to CRLF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True format. `echo` instead of `echno` and fixed double quotes `" "`

```
if($send_contact){
    echo "Thank You! <a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'> Return Home </a>";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this `a href` missing `<` ;-)

Comment: Oh and the OP wrote `echno` and not `encho` as you stated in your answer. And it's `quotes` and not `qoutes` ;-) *Helping along...*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ahh my crappy english ;) Thanks

Comment: No problemo, glad I could help ;-) (`+1`)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the following code

```
echno "Thank You!" "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'> Return Home </a>";
   ^             ^ ^
echno "ERROR";
   ^
```

You either need to remove the two double quotes or concantinate the string with the `.` operator.

```
echo "Thank You! <a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'> Return Home </a>";
```

Also `echno` is not a thing, the correct name is `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
if($send_contact){
echno "Thank You!" "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'>        Return Home </a>";
} else {
   echno "ERROR";
}
```

to

```
if($send_contact){ 

    echo "Thank You! "."<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'> Return Home </a>";
                   // ^ Here the point
} else {

    echo "ERROR";
}
```

or (Updated)

```
if($send_contact){ 

    echo "Thank You! <a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none; color:#4fa9b8;'> Return Home </a>";
                 // ^ Eliminated double quotes
} else {

    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Don't exist `echno` and between the both string you forget the `.` or to eliminate the `" "`

Comment: You can save the OP 3 keystrokes by omitting `"."` altogether.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes..I know :-)